# In IE10+Win7 a ASP.NET ImageButton only works in Compatibility Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, imagebutton

The following is the markup for the for my login piece and the ImageButton (they all are withing a ):

```
         <tr style="width:150">
             <td style="padding-left:0px;font-family:Verdana;font-size:70%;width:30%;font-size:small;">Username</td>
            <td style="width:70%" align="left"><asp:TextBox id="txtUsername" runat="server" Width="90px" /></td>
            <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUserName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtUsername" ValidationGroup="credentials" Display="Dynamic" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
               <td style="padding-left:0px;font-family:Verdana;font-size:70%;font-size:small;" >Password</td>
               <td style="padding-right:0px;font-size:small;" align="left"><asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server" Width="90px" /></td>
               <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPassword" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ValidationGroup="credentials" Display="Dynamic" /></td>
         </tr>
         <asp:Panel ID="pnlInvalidCredentials" runat="server" >
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2" align="center" style="color: Red;">
               <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litInvalidCredentials" Text="Invalid Username or Password" />
               </td>
            </tr>
         </asp:Panel>
     <tr valign="middle">
        <td style="padding-left:20px;" valign="top"><asp:ImageButton ID="ibLogin" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Sign_in_button.png" OnClick="ibLogin_OnClick" Width="83px" Height="25px"  /></td>
           <td align="center" style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:70%;font-size:small;">
              <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbForgotPassword" Text="Forgot password?" OnClick="lbForgotPassword_OnClick" />                                                             
           </td>
     </tr>
```

Also the very first line of `ibLogin_Click(...)` is `Debug.WriteLine("ImageButton clicked.");`.  In IE10 on Win7 if I am not in Compatibility Mode when I click the button, nothing happens.  The code-behind OnClick is never called (I never see "ImageButton clicked." in my debug output and login doesn't occur).

However, if I turn Compatibility Mode on, everything instantly works, and I of course I see "ImageButton clicked" in my debug output and a successful login happens.

Am I using the ImageButton incorrectly in my markup?  Is there known issues with

Answer (score 0):

I would do a few things to see why it doesn't work. First thing I would do would be use the "F12 Developer Tools" and use that to see what may be happening. Sometimes it might be showing that something is being blocked. This way you can see if it is being fired or not. If you are unable to find anything useful in that, try resetting your Internet Explorer. You would do this by selecting internet options, click the advance key, and reset.  I have run into issues where IE was just messed up from me constantly debugging. I would also check to see if it works on Firefox and Chrome. As for you code, the image button looks fine. To me, this is going to be a issue with your actual browser and not your code. You could also try uninstalling IE 10 and see if it works without compatibility mode in IE 9. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in IE10 that pertains directly to ASP.NET ImageButton controls.  The problem can be solved simply by replacing the control with an ASP.NET Button and styling it to look how you want.